# Css - fix container, overflow inside block

Tags: css

I have a fixed sized container and a children inside. The content of the children is variable.
I need to expand the children to the length of the content. If I use a fixed width for the childred, the browser will display a scoll bar. Any good solution for this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/vMyhn/2/
Blue should stay fixed.
Green should be extended over blue so the text will be in a single line.
No fixed width for the green box.

Comment: please use jsfiddle to show us what the problem is.

Comment: A little info on what the content is would be nice, text/image? dimensions etc...

Comment: This is still very confusing for me. What I do not understand is whether you want the "long content" to be in a single line or wrapped. I am assuming my first answer below is not what you want. Any chance you can add an image of what you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Give container:

```
overflow: hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want long content, you can use CSS is preserve the spaces with this.

```
<div style="width:1000px">
    <span style="white-space:pre-wrap">        abc         abc         abc         abc         abc         abc         abc     abc</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Do you want the children to size according to the width of the parent? Use this CSS: (colours and padding added to show you that the children size to the width of the parent)</strike>

```
.container {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    background: Blue;
}

.content {
    background: Green;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/TVJB9/1/

Do you want the children to size according to their content? Use this CSS: (colours and padding added to show you that the children size to the width of their content)

```
.container {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    background: Blue;
}

.content {
    background: Green;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vMyhn/1/

And after your update I manged to make what you asked, quote "Blue should stay fixed. Green should be extended over blue so the text will be in a single line. No fixed width for the green box." However I fail to see the purpose of Blue in this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vMyhn/3/